# stop mysql_fetch_array when reach username

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code to get the list of users from the database and sort them by score.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY score DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

What I want to do, is to stop the loop proces, when the proces reach a decided username.

Comment: Er... You're aware of the `WHERE` clause, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to stop the loop?

Comment: It looks like a leaderboard potentially showing a list of users down to the current users name - this assumption could be wrong though.  It could be done using a MySQL variable of some kind but that's not really what the user asked.

Comment: why you don't use WHERE in sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` with `if` condition

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($rows['name'] == 'yourname') {
        break;
    }else {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY score DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if($row['username']=='DecidedUser')
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WHERE in mysql query like this.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='targetUserName' ORDER BY score DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Here user_name is mysql fieldname in users table.

Answer (score 0):

use break;

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY score DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(Reached_at_user_name)
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`break;` is your friend

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if (
        $row['username'] == 'username'
    ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

An alternative approach depending on your intention would be to just change the SQL query to do what you want instead, i.e. something like the following which uses the @includeThis variable to keep track of if it's hit the intended username yet

```
$sql="
    SELECT 
        u.*, 
        @includeThis AS includeThis,
        @includeThis := IF(u.username = 'TargetUserName',0,@includeThis) AS updateIncludeThis
    FROM users u, (SELECT @includeThis := 1) d 
    ORDER BY u.score DESC
    HAVING includeThis = 1
";
```

Additionally you shouldn't be using the mysql_ functions any more, and instead using mysqli_ or PDO.  [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

inside your while you want to add something along the lines of.

```
if($rows['username'] == "targetUserName"){return;}
```

You could also use `break;` instead of return, however with return you can `return true;` to let your script know your function found the username, if required :)